# Getting Missing jaxb-runtime api error after Migrate Spring boot 1.5 to 2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

As you can see I am Not using any jax-runtime or jax-api dependency in my pom file, Despite this i am getting error missing jax related jar in my .m2 repository path.
Issue occured after Migrating my Spring boot project from 1.5.x to 2.1.3 with java 1.8.

Comment: I suggest posting your pom and a full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is no longer provided in the JRE after Java 8.  In a Spring Boot application, add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependency>                                                                
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>                                         
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>                                         
    </dependency>
```